# Why doesn't the Bashir Changeling slay Deep Space Nine's senior staff?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, star-trek-dominion, changeling, julian-bashir

During the Dominion War, after Dr. Bashir is replaced aboard the station with a Changeling, why doesn't the Changeling at least attempt to kill the senior staff? Killing the staff would likely be relatively easy, all things considered. And certainly the loss of Sisko, Kira, Dax, and O'Brien would be a blow for the Federation.

The real-world reason is obvious. What in-universe reason presents itself?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm doing this from the top of my head, without re-watching the episode(s) in question.

Killing the senior staff would be easy, except for the timing.  If they all were murdered early on in the mission, it would raise holy heck.  Obviously the work of a Dominion agent, and since it would be difficult for a jem'hadar to hide in the ventilation shafts of DS9, everyone would suspect a changeling.  A changeling running loose would raise paranoia across the quadrant, lock the station down on double-secret red alert and generally make the Great Sun Flare Mission far more difficult.

Killing the senior staff closer to the checkmate move of the Flare event shows an astounding lack of confidence in the entire grand strategy.  DS9 and three fleets would all be killed in one stroke.  Why bother?

Perhaps in a last microsecond "d'Oh!" before being vaporized, the changeling had this exact regret.

Comment: Upvote for the last line. :)

Comment: The Dominion didn't every think small and wanted to dominate the federation.  Also the life of one changeling is more important then anything to them.  Honestly I don't think they would have ever consider peace if Odo wasn't involved.

Answer (score 4):

The Bashir Changeling was plotting to blow up the Bajoran sun.  Unsolved murders would only arouse suspicion and jeopardize the plan.  Plus had the Changeling won, all the senior staff would've died in a glorious supernova.